# How to convert this data into JSon format and POST this data to server?

Tags: android, json, string

I have following string,

String Action="CreateUser";
String company="company name";

But how to convert above string same as below json string and pass this string to server

```
{"action":"CreateUser","user":{"company":{"solutionname":"","createdon":"","companyguid":"","nextinvoicenumber":"1000","companystatus":"Active","companyname":"","solutioncode":"InvoiceASAP"},"createdon":"","userstatus":"Active","companyguid":"","addressguid":"","guid":"","firstname":"Renuka","lastname":"Shah","email":"ren40@vprex.com","username":"","password":"renuka","cellphone":"","homephone":"","officephone":"","officeextension":"","faxnumber":"","phoneid":"1","sourceid":"1","primarycontact":"Y","permissioncode":"COMPANYADMIN","address":{"addr1":"","addr2":"","addr3":"","addr4":"","addr5":"","city":"","state":"","postalcode":"","country":"","note":""}}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it not already available as a String?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and do you face any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as following: http://snipplr.com/view/53225/

```
String Action="CreateUser"; String company="company name";
try
    {
        JSONObject action=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject user=new JSONObject();
        action.put("action", Action);
        action.put("user", user);

        JSONObject company=new JSONObject();
        user.put("company", company);
        user.put("userstatus", "Active");

        company.put("solutionname", "");
        company.put("nextinvoicenumber", "1000");
        //.... 
    }
    catch (Exception je)
    {

    }
```

and then pass the `JSONObject` (`action`) to the server..

Comment: then how to post this json string to server?

Comment: May be this http://forum.codecall.net/topic/62526-send-a-json-object-to-a-server/ will help

Answer (score 0):

You will have put put values into a JSONObject in the form of name-value pairs.

Like this:

```
public void writeJSON() {
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject user2;
    user2 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        user.put("dish_id", "1");
        user.put("dish_custom", "2");
        user.put("quantity", "2");
        user.put("shared", "2");

        user2.put("dish_id", "2");
        user2.put("dish_custom", "2");
        user2.put("quantity", "4");
        user2.put("shared", "3");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```